# jsp session timing out

Tags: jsp

I have a jsp page with a button . When the user clicks the button, it starts a particular operation (data processing) on the server.
The problem is that if the size of the data is big , the jsp page crashes after a few minutes and I see an error message : "IE cannot display the page". 
However , the server processing is not affected and runs to completion.

I think that the jsp session may be timing out .
Why is this happening and what can I do to solve it ?

I am using Apache Tomcat web server.

Comment: It's not the session, it's the request, that times out. Use some form of a "wait" page.

Comment: Hi Dave, Thanks a lot for your reply , but can you please give me some more details about "wait" page , since I am new to JSP.